# Ejecución de condionales para renders. ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Es válida la siguiente ejecución condicional?

```
<Route path="/" render={() => isReg ?   ( cliente ?  <HomeCliente /> : <HomeProveedor /> ) : <Inicio /> } />
```

La misma está implementada de la siguiente manera, donde isReg y cliente son hooks que toman valores booleanos.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [isReg, setIsReg] = useState(false);
  const [cliente, setCliente] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(renderAgain){
      console.log("render again igual a true")
    }
    getItem("isRegistered").then(res => {
      if (res!=null){
        setIsReg(true);
        getItem("clientType").then(res => {
          console.log("tipo de cliente: "+res)
          if (res=="1"){
            console.log("entonces es igual a 1 el tipo de cliente")
            setCliente(true)
          }else{
            console.log("entonces es igual a 2 o 3 el tipo de cliente")
            setCliente(false)
          }
          
        })

      }
      else{
        setIsReg(false);
      }
    });
}, []);

return(
<IonApp>
<IonReactRouter>
<IonSplitPane contentId="main" when="(min-width: 4096px)">
      <Menu renderAgain={renderAgain} />
  <IonRouterOutlet id="main">

    <Route path="/" render={() => isReg ?   ( cliente ?  <HomeCliente /> : <HomeProveedor /> ) : <Inicio /> } />

  </IonRouterOutlet>
  </IonSplitPane>
</IonReactRouter>
</IonApp>

);
};

export default App;
```

Comment: ¿Te funcionó? Saludos

Comment: Claro que es válida, ¿tienes algún problema con tu código?

Answer (score 0):

Sí, es valida, pero es mejor tener lógica fuera del router. Por ejemplo, tener un component `Home` que va hacer todo el trabajo:

```
<Route path="/" render={Home} />
```

Y en `Home` puede hacer la lógica requisa y cambiar entre `Inicio` y páginas de cliente.

También es una buena idea encapsular la lógica para autenticación y rol en un [React Context Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) y crear un hook que se puede usar en `Home`. React Context es un poco difícil y no es absolutamente necesario pero ayuda a separar lógica para que no tengas todo en su `App.js`.

También puedes crear un hook, por ejemplo `useAppRole()` y usarlo en `Home` para saber el rol:

```
const { role } = useAppRole()
```

Es una buena idea usar Context porque otras páginas va a necesitar la información y mejor buscarla solamente una vez.

Puede ser que la lógica es la misma que tiene pero la arquitectura es mejor así. Si no separas la lógica, puede ser que todo el código va estar en `App.js`. Puede ver un ejemplo en Code Sandbox aquí: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-architecture-w-context-provider-txb06?file=/src/Home.js

En el ejemplo también tengo `loading` para indicar que estamos buscando el app rol.